# VHDL port external names and procedure modes

Tags: vhdl, simulation, external, procedure

Using Modelsim 10.7b (VHDL-2008), I am confused by the behavior of VHDL *external names* when passed in to a `procedure`. In particular, I see a wide variety of different behavior depending on whether the *external name* references a `port` or a `signal`, and whether I use mode `in` or `inout`.

The only book I have that covers *external names* ([Ashenden, 3rd Ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120887851)) only gives one trivial example of a `port`, but just implies it's exactly the same as a signal: "*This reflects the rule in VHDL that a port is considered to be a signal declared within an entity*". It doesn't appear to cover what happens in a `procedure`.

Therefore, my question is whether someone can provide an explanation for the observed behavior in each of the following 3 simple test cases.

**an_entity.vhd**:

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity an_entity is
    port (
        i   : in std_logic
    );
end;

architecture rtl of an_entity is
    signal s    : std_logic;
begin
    s <= i;
end;
```

**tb.vhd**:

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity tb;

architecture rtl of tb is

    procedure procedure_with_mode_in(signal x : in std_logic) is
    begin
        x <= force '1';
    end procedure;

    procedure procedure_with_mode_inout(signal x : inout std_logic) is
    begin
        x <= force '1';
    end procedure;

    signal i    : std_logic := '0';

begin

    uut : entity work.an_entity
    port map(
        i   => i
    );

    process
    begin

        -- ### COPY-PASTE TEST CASE HERE ###

        wait;
    end process;

end architecture rtl;
```

### SANITY CHECK: No procedure call

```
wait for 10 ns;
<<signal uut.i : std_logic>> <= force '1';
wait for 10 ns;
<<signal uut.i : std_logic>> <= release;
```

**Result**: Forces and releases successfully:

[image: Test 1 Result]

### TEST CASE 1: Procedure called on `port`, mode `in`

```
wait for 10 ns;
procedure_with_mode_in(<<signal uut.i : std_logic>>);
wait for 10 ns;
<<signal uut.i : std_logic>> <= release;
```

**Result**: Forces but doesn't release:

(Note: Result is the same if procedure is called on a `signal` external name).

[image]

### TEST CASE 2: Procedure called on `port`, mode `inout`

```
wait for 10 ns;
procedure_with_mode_inout(<<signal uut.i : std_logic>>);
wait for 10 ns;
<<signal uut.i : std_logic>> <= release;
```

**Result**: Error:

```sh
# ** Error: (vsim-8509) The object class "SIGNAL(read/driven)" of "uut.i" is different from the class "VHDL INPUT PORT" of the denoted object.  
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb File: C:/path/tb.vhd Line: 32
```

### TEST CASE 3: Procedure called on `signal`, mode `inout`

```
wait for 10 ns;
procedure_with_mode_inout(<<signal uut.s : std_logic>>);
wait for 10 ns;
<<signal uut.s : std_logic>> <= release;
```

**Result**: Signal is undefined, but forces and releases:

[image]

Comment: Don't display diagnostic messages as images. The text can't show up in search.

Comment: Yes, I already thought about that. If I get an answer, I'll add it as text. My Modelsim is busy right now and I don't want to type it out by hand!

Comment: Thanks. To address both these comments, I have edited my question to replace the error image with raw text, excluding the irrelevant FLI error.

Comment: Having looked at this more closely, I think an important detail may be that `force '1'` will always evaluate to either `force in '1'` or `force out '1'`. The default force mode depends on the mode of the `port` or `signal` it is applied to. Once you put the `force` inside a `procedure`, this default mode is perhaps determined from the mode of the `signal` argument of the procedure and not from the original `port`. The default `force` mode for a signal/port of type `inout` is `force out`.